# Javascript : click() method doesn't click the link

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, visualstudio

I have link with below properties on my Webpage:

```
<li class="XXXX" title="This is test"> TestLink </li>
```

I am trying with below code for clicking on above link with Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("XX")[2]
a.click()
```

but it shows result **'undefined'**.

Also when I check events available for this link with

```
getEventListeners(a)->
```

it's showing:

```
blank {}
```

Please help me to click on this link.

Comment: You need to provide your HTML here, as well as the class you used

Comment: I added html code in first para but i think editor converted it to link.Here is the html code :  <li class="wux-layouts-treeview-label" title="Shared with me">Shared with me</li>

Comment: Where is your javascript code to perform click function?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **XPath**, **linkText** or **className** to locate your Link object.

By **XPath:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='This is test']"));
```

By **linkText:**

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("TestLink"));
```

**Code to Perform Click:**

```
WebElement ele_Link= driver.findElement(By.linkText("TestLink"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele_Link);
```

Comment: Thank you Bharat for the answer and it will work in selenium. But i am using Visual Studio code to write the javascript code and driver is unknown there(we have to use document instead). I have tried many options with my javascript by even adding the explicit event for click of that link. But no success :(

Comment: Ohh..Please edit your question particular for Visual Studio. You can post the same one on Stackoverflow. Will update you if I got any info on how it works in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("XX");
a[2].click();
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: That was the first code i tried, but unfortunately it didn't work.